# MongoDB Change Stream reading data which are old updates

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, changestream

I have created an application which reads mongo change stream for updates and inserts and then we take action on the changed data. Below is my code snippet

```
private void listenChangeStream() {
        Runnable changeListener = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String fullDoc = null;
                String updateInfo = null;

                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        ChangeStreamDocument<Document> next = cursor.next();
                        String id = next.getDocumentKey().getString("id").getValue();
                        LOGGER.debug("Change Stream recived:{}", next);
                        String operationType = next.getOperationType().getValue();
                        if ("insert".equals(operationType) || "replace".equals(operationType)) {
                               fullDoc = next.getFullDocument().toString();
                            if (fullDoc.contains("image_info")) {
                                kafkaProducer
                                        .pushOfflineProcessingData(new DataPackets(Id, OfflineProcessType.IMAGE));
                            }
                        } else if ("update".equals(operationType)) {
                               updateInfo = next.getUpdateDescription().toString();
                            if (updateInfo.contains("image_info"))
                                kafkaProducer
                                        .pushOfflineProcessingData(new DataPackets(Id, OfflineProcessType.IMAGE));
                        } 

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        LOGGER.info("Exception has come in cahnge listener::", ex);
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        executor.execute(changeListener);

    }

private MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> getCursor(MongoCollection<Document> supplierCollection, List<Bson> pipeline) {
        MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor;     
             cursor = supplierCollection.watch(pipeline).iterator();        
        return cursor;
    }
```

This is working fine.
The problem which i am facing is when ever i start the server the change stream starts reading old committed changes . Which i do not want. I want after the deployment only the new updates should be picked by this.

Can any one suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

> Can any one suggest how to do it?

In MongoDB v4.0 with MongoDB Java driver v3.8, you can specify `startAtOperationTime` parameter to [MongoClient.watch()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html#watch).

The change stream will only provides changes that occurred after the specified timestamp. Any command run against the MongoDB server will return an operation time that can be used as a value of the parameter. The default value is an operation time obtained from the server before the change stream was created.

Alternatively, you could also cache the last seen `_id` from the change stream notification. This is a `resumeToken` that you could pass to `resumeAfter()` method to resume notifications starting after the operation specified in the `resumeToken`. For example:

```
BsonDocument resumeToken = next.getResumeToken();
cursor = inventory.watch().resumeAfter(resumeToken).iterator();
```

See also [MongoDB Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)